# How to trigger click event on anchor when clicking parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a clickable container. When clicked then the click event on the first child anchor should be triggered.

Html looks something like this:

```
<div class="click-area">
    <p>test test test</p>
    <a href="#next">link</a>
</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
$(".click-area").click(function () {
    $(this).find("a").first().click();
});
```

but this will result in a "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" javascript error.

I have also tried this:

```
$(".click-area").click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").first().prop('href');
    return false;
});
```

this will work on some links.

But I also have some links that should launch Bootstrap modals

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">link modal</a>
```

and the window.location method will not work here...

Is this possible? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/casperskovgaard/3Layy9dr/)

Comment: A clickable element within a clickable element is asking for problems. Why this structure?

Comment: @Mikey you are right this is giving me a headache. If you have an idea for an alternative structure, please feel free to post it as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close the first time, but caused recursion as the simulated click event propagates back to `click-area`. Use e.stopPropagation():

You may think that means this:

```
$(".click-area").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find("a").first().click();
});
```

But actually, that is not quite right as it is the anchor you must stop propagating:

Stop propagation from the anchor only with a new handler:

```
$(".click-area").click(function (e) {
    $(this).find("a").first().click();
});

$(".click-area a").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

If you have problems with the jQuery click not firing (e.g. because of external page links in a JSFiddle etc), try using `domelement[0].click()` (at least for testing):

```
$(".click-area").click(function (e) {
    $(this).find("a")[0].click();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3Layy9dr/7/

Comment: Interesting Fiddle. Only `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` should have caused that. Will investigate your JSFiddle.

Comment: It is your links causing the problem... They apparently reload the same page: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3Layy9dr/6/ Added workaround for JSFiddle issues.

Comment: target="_blank" is not a good solution. Links should open in same window. And the modal link should open a bootstrap model

Comment: @CasperSkovgaard: *That was only for the JSFiddle*. Normal links have to be valid to work there. Your links are not valid for a JSFiddle :) Basically have you tried the suggested changes in your page?

Comment: I have created this test page: http://www.metz-dev.dk/dev/test.nsf/click-area.html and it is still not working

Comment: @CasperSkovgaard: Of course your sample will do nothing... Your links are all *bookmark links to the same page*... what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: here is the same page without any js: http://www.metz-dev.dk/dev/test.nsf/click-area-nojs.html Click first link and url will change, second link a modal is shown and third link google.com is loaded. The same should happen when clicking the parent div.

Comment: The problem on that page seems to be other plugins. Have you tried the version with `$(this).find("a")[0].click();` on that page? It will hit the native click event on the DOM element. Should fire anything connected

Comment: $(this).find("a")[0].click(); is working much better. Still the bootstrap is not launched but I'll find another way to launch it. Thanks for the help. Here is the last test I made: http://www.metz-dev.dk/dev/test.nsf/click-area-1.html

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do something more like:

```
$(".click-area").click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
});
```

Comment: this will not launch the bootstrap modal